# Difference between gets vs scanf vs fgets in C programming

Tags: c

I've recently started learning C programming language and saw these three input function in 3 different books. So I'm little confused about which one to use when efficiency is considered.

Comment: I tried searching in the stackflow but couldn't find one that time. So added the question. Anyway thank you folks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So I'm little confused about which one to use when efficiency is considered.

None of them. I/O is slow. If you need efficiency, don't do I/O. Or, what's more likely is that you don't *really* need efficiency but you need I/O and you are optimizing prematurely.

Apart from that, here's the difference:

- `gets()` is dangerous and has been removed from the standard, don't use it.
- `scanf()` is standard, but it's clumsy and hard to use correctly. Apart from very specialized use cases, it's not worth bothering with it.
- `fgets()` is easier to use correctly and it is the preferred way of getting raw untrusted user input (i. e. user input in general). It can also read from any `FILE *` stream, not only `stdin`.

Comment: +1,very beautifully illustrated!

Comment: The exact brief answer that I needed.. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`gets()` reads always from standard input (`stdin`)

`fgets()` can read from an input stream (e.g. a file you open explicitly)

So, `gets()` is equal to `fgets()` with third parameter as `stdin`.

At last, `scanf()` can read formatted input data, parse it and set values to pointers you give.

Never use `gets()`. It offers no protections against a buffer overflow vulnerability.

Avoid using `scanf()`. If not used carefully, it can have the same buffer overflow problems as `gets()`.

You should use `fgets()` instead, although it's sometimes inconvenient.

Comment: "gets() is equal to fgets() with third parameter as stdin" Hmmmm -  A difference is with `gets()`: newline character, if found, is not copied.  newline character, if found, is copied with `fgets()`.

Comment: Yes, you can remove it explicitly "string[strlen(string) - 1] = '\0';

Comment: `string[strlen(string) - 1] = '\0` is a problem as it leads to trouble in the exceptional cases when `strlen(string) == 0`.  Methods exist to [quickly](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67608/trimming-fgets-strlen-or-strtok) and safely remove the `'\n'`

Comment: Of course you have to check the length of the string and if the last character is the newline character. That was to easy to add it here.