# weird error when execute a command typed from keyboard on Linux with C

Tags: c, linux, scanf

I'm studying code C on Linux.

I have a program to execute a command line which is typed from keyboard.

This is my code

```
char* command;
scanf("%s", command);
execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, NULL);
```

and it print out nothing.

But the weird thing is: If a do not enter the command line from keyboard anymore and I assign value for the variable, then it work like this:

```
char* command;
command = "ls -l";
execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, NULL);
```

Can anyone show me why my code doesn't work with `scanf()`

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char* command;
scanf("%s", command);
```

memory is not allocated to command when scanf is being called so its leading to undefined behaviour, you should allocate memory by either

```
command = malloc(256);
```

or 
declare it as

```
char command[256];
```

Comment: Sorry, this is a very bad practice. I'm really not saying this because I had the second answer but because readers of this question might think that this is the way to go, and it's simply not. There are lots of links about this like [this one](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) and [this one](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955466/difference-between-gets-vs-scanf-vs-fgets-in-c-programming?noredirect=1&lq=1). If you understand C, you know that not everything that works is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` is used to read a char, not a string (it might work sometimes but it's really error-prone). use `fgets` from standard input instead.

Example:

```
char str[STR_LEN];
fgets(str, STR_LEN , stdin);
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302255/c-scanf-vs-gets-vs-fgets) answer about the differences between them.